# rich:dataGrid borders issue rich faces 4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We are upgrading from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2. 
We are using apache myfaces 2.1 and rich faces 4.3.

The issue is i am not able to get borders around `<rich:dataGrid>` component.
I have seen posts describing how to remove the borders but no one specifies how to get borders. 
It seems that borders are by default rendered earlier (they were coming when rich faces 3 is used  ) but after upgrading to rich faces 4 , ther are not rendered
by default.
Following is the xhtml snippet.

```
<rich:dataGrid value="#{bean.getListValues}"  var="value" columns="1" rowKeyVar="index" id="qsns"
style="border-bottom-width:10px;">


        <h:panelGrid id="qsn#{index+1}"  border="10" columns="2">

                   <h:outputText value="qsn #{index+1}"/>
                   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{value.qsn}">
                 <f:selectItems value="#{bean.qsnPool}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu> 


                <h:outputText value="Answer"/>                                            
                    <h:inputText value="#{value.answer}"/>


        </h:panelGrid>  


</rich:dataGrid>
```

I also tried setting borders explicitely for panelGrid (border="10") in above snippet.
and to rich:dataGrid (border-bottom-width:10px), but it is not working as specified in url according to url : http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids.html#sect-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids-richlist

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get the desired behavoiur by following changes

```
.tableClass1 .rf-dg-c{   
      border: 1px solid #000;
}
table.tableClass1.rf-dg{     
     border-collapse:collapse;
}


<rich:dataGrid value="#{bean.getListValues}"  var="value" columns="1" rowKeyVar="index" id="qsns"
styleClass="tableClass1">

        <h:panelGrid id="qsn#{index+1}"  border="10" columns="2">

                 <h:outputText value="qsn #{index+1}"/>
                 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{value.qsn}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.qsnPool}" />
                 </h:selectOneMenu> 


                 <h:outputText value="Answer"/>                                            
                 <h:inputText value="#{value.answer}"/>


        </h:panelGrid>  

</rich:dataGrid>
```

With above style classes and xhtml code , borders are perfectly rendered.

First style sheet renders borders for grid cells and second style sheet collapses 
the space between adjacent cell borders (since cellspacing attribute doesn't work for rich:dataGrid)

The above selectors apply only to local `<rich:dataGrid>` , that means not affecting globally for all `<rich:dataTables>`

Answer (score 1):

The `border-bottom-width:10px;` isn't working because the `border-bottom-style` is `none`.

The borders around `<rich:datagrid>` aren't defined on one element. The left and top borders are defined on the datagrid, class `rf-dg`. The bottom and right are defined on the grid cells, class `rf-dg-c`. You'll have to overwrite the classes if you want to change all the borders.

Comment: @markhiel:Actually did the same thing and able to resolve the issue. But problem with above approach is it applies globally so need to create style sheet selector exclusively for <rich:dataGrid>.But again problem is <rich:dataGrid> in rich faces 4 doesn't support row and columnClasses.So need to modify ui a little bit to get the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The border attribute is not doing much, try using CSS styling:

```
 <h:panelGrid style="border: 1px solid #000;"> ...
```

Or use CSS via classes:

```
<h:panelGrid styleClass="myClass"> ...
```

In your CSS:

```
.myClass {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for your help. It worked. Issue now is can we reduce space between each panelGrid to zero ? Every panel grid is rendered with borders but with spaces in between . I want to reduce the space to zero.

Comment: I recommend you learn CSS as you will need it in some places.

Comment: I am able to get the desired behaviour by overriding the default css properties of <rich:dataGrid> . They are .rf-dg-c .I am able to reduce the space with this.But Thanks for your answer too.