# Rich Faces dataTable StyleClass Issue

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

**Version :**

Apache MyFaces 2.1.14
Rich Faces 4.3.5

**Issue :**

We are migrating from JSF1.2 to JSF2. The issue is the style for headerClass is not getting applied correctly for rich:dataTable.
When debugged , it seems that rich faces overrides the headerClass style with its own styles.
The syle selector .rf-dt-hdr-c of rich faces overrides the custom style sheet selector.
(We want to replace the colour of header with custom header image)

Finally , when rich faces supplied style `(.rf-dt-hdr-c)` is overriden like shown in code below , it worked.
But since it is rich faces built in style , it will be applied to every rich:dataTable which may not be a good option.
The approch as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627182/richdatagrid-borders-issue-rich-faces-4/20685835#20685835)  which is similar , is not working here since there is no provision to combine custom style with built in one.
Is there any better approach available to solve this issue ? 
Is there any way custom style can be applied alongwith .rf-dt-hdr-c so that it won't effect globally ?
Please help.

**Code :**

**Rich data Table snippet :**

```
 <rich:dataTable id="admin" headerClass="richTableHeader1" styleClass="richDataTable1" rowClasses="evenRow,oddRow" 
                    columnClasses="columnRow" value="#{bean.list}" var="val">
```

**Styles :**

```
.richDataTable1{    
    width:100%; 
}

<!-- this is the headerClass style used to apply custom image (not working )-->
.richTableHeader1{

    background-image:url(../images/heading1.gif) !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

<!-- rich faces applied style overriden (working )-->
.rf-dt-hdr-c{
    background-image:url(../images/heading1.gif) !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a table header:

```
<thead id="form:j_idt10:th" class="rf-dt-thd">
    <tr id="form:j_idt10:h" class="rf-dt-hdr">
        <th class="rf-dt-hdr-c" colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Table</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

`@headerClass` is applied to the `tr.rf-dt-hdr` element. So you have to change your definition to

```
.richTableHeader1 th {
    background-image:url(../images/heading1.gif) !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `@headerCellClass`, it is not a documented feature but it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Makhiel. Both approaches worked perfectly fine. I was struggling a lot for this.Only thing is , i couldn't understand the reason behind using .richTableHeader1 th instead .richTableHeader1 tr . I mean why this combination only.

Comment: Hi Makhiel, understood the reason for using .richTableHeader1 th. Thanks a lot.